# How do I rename a file with a "\" in the filename?

Tags: rename

I backed up a PS2 memory card to an SD card a couple months ago. I'm currently backing it up to my PC but there's some files that are either too long or have forward slashes in the filenames. Is there any way I can rename these files?

Comment: What operating system and filesystem are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 and the filesystem of the SD Card is FAT32. Hard drive I'm trying to move it to is NTFS.

Comment: Robocopy may be able to help. it is often capable copying files that violate rules. As for renaming them, once they are on NTFS, review this document: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume . you might also have some luck using a linux live-cd, though i doubt it could help with the forward slashes.

Comment: Linux could probably help with `\\`, which is a _backward_ slash.